# What library of MathJax is preferred to draw mathematical diagram?

Tags: diagram, mathjax

I am searching a MathJax library to draw mathmatical diagram.

I had used XyJax.js when my MathJax version was 2.75.

But my current MathJax version is 3, and under that version XyJax seems not to work.

So now I need the MathJax library which is adequate with MathJax version 3.

Supplementation: I want the MathJax library which has plenty function because I will draw a complex diagram.

Comment: What's your tech stack, do you have any code?